# Access parent windows form in backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, messagebox

I have an extended method for `messagebox.Show()`, which uses `IWin32Window` of the parent winform to center the `MessageBox` on it.

However, I can't seem to understand how can we possibly use this same extension method to pop-up `MessageBox` on the main/parent winform from within `BackgroundWorker`.

The extension method is something like this:

```
MessageBoxExTn.Show(IWin32Window parentForm, string MsgText, string Caption, MessageBoxButtons);
```

I mean, I want to call this method from `BackgroundWorker's` `DoWork` event with threadsafe access to the parent/main winform.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another method on your Main Form  and do something like this

```
public void ShowMessage(string cap,string message)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Action<string, string> action = ShowMessage;
            this.Invoke(action, new object[] {cap, message});
            return;
        }

       MessageBoxExTn.Show(IWin32Window parentForm, string MsgText, string Caption, MessageBoxButtons);
    }
```

please take a look at [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to understand more thread-safe in  windows form

call  your code

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
           ShowMessage(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use event in this case and fire event when you want to show the message box. Now in your parent/main form handle this event and show the message box. This way you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage the `BackgroundWorker` event `ProgressChanged`. This will do the thread switching for you. So imagine something like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxExTn.Show(parentForm,
        e.UserState as string,
        someCaption,
        MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

and that's called like this:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, "The message you want displayed.");
```